# Query Firebase data based on Date which is a Node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database is like this

[image]

What i am trying to do is get **DailyData** based on Date,which is a string.

I tried `dbRef.child("DailyData").endAt("20 April 2020")`
 but its giving all the five nodes,
where as it should give only 3 nodes upto `20 April 2020`

Please do help in solving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not ordering by anything yet. Without an explicit ordering, the child nodes will be ordered by (a nowadays meaningless) priority, and apparently all priority values are less than `"20..."`.

You'll want to order by key here, so:

```
dbRef.child("DailyData").orderByKey().endAt("20 April 2020")
```

Comment: Thanks.. One question though.. Isn't it firebase-query a tag. I put that tag,but was removed by Doug. Might have been useful though.